# problem with linked label to focused Input Restrictions in html / css

Tags: html, css, input, focus, onfocus

I created a form submit on html/css... pls check it out in this link below
https://codepen.io/letsimoo/pen/PobxGRG

### HTML Code

```
<form action="">
<div class="container">
  <input class="required-input" type="text" id="name" required />
  <label class="required-label" for="name">Name:</label>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <input class="required-input" type="text" id="email" required />
  <label class="required-label" for="email">Email:</label>
</div>

  
<div class="container" >
  <input class="not-required-input" type="text" id="budget"/>
  <label class="not-required-label" for="budget">Budget:</label>  
</div>
  
  
<div class="container">
  <input class="required-input" type="text" id="Message" required  style="height: 100px"/>
  <label class="required-label" for="Message">Message:</label>    
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
```

### CSS Code

```
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*Just to center the Form*/
form {
  height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

/* A container to position LABELS */
.container {
  position: relative;
  /*            top: auto;
            left: auto;
            width: auto; */
}

.required-input {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #eee, #fff 0 1px 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #eee, #fff 0 1px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;

  background-color: black;
  color: lightgray;
}

/* I put label on top of the input*/
.required-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 0.5em;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 1em;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 3.5em;
  color: #999;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: text;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

/*      making exception for Budget */
.not-required-input {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #eee, #fff 0 1px 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #eee, #fff 0 1px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;

  background-color: black;
  color: lightgray;
}

.not-required-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 0.5em;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 1em;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 3.5em;
  color: #999;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: text;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

.required-input:focus ~ .required-label,
.required-input:valid ~ .required-label {
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 5px;
  top: -5px;
}

/*      making exception for Budget */
.not-required-input:focus ~ .not-required-label,
.not-required-input:invalid ~ .not-required-label {
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 5px;
  top: -5px;
}

.required-input:valid ~ .required-label {
  color: #497495;
}

.required-input:focus:invalid ~ .required-label {
  color: red;
}

.required-input:required ~ .required-label::before {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
}

.required-input:required:valid ~ .required-label::before {
  color: #497495;
}
```

The only issue that I'm facing in this form is when selecting the (not-required) field which is (Budget) as you saw in the link after finish writing in that field or after it get unfocused, the label back to its old position and value!

Can you help me to figure out where is the mistake in the elements selection and what shall I do instead please?

Ps. when I set the input restriction of (Budget) to *required it will not have any problem!

Comment: look - https://jsfiddle.net/Prajeesh_PR/ke17nsrh/

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Thx bro your code helped me to get what i want

Comment: no problem, bro :)

Answer (score 0):

You have `:invalid` for an element that can't be invalid. Since it doesn't have `required`, it will always come out as `invalid`. My answer comes from [this blog](https://zellwk.com/blog/check-empty-input-css/#invalidating-the-input).

```css
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*Just to center the Form*/
form {
  height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

/* A container to position LABELS */
.container {
  position: relative;
  /*            top: auto;
            left: auto;
            width: auto; */
}

/*      making exception for Budget */
.not-required-input {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #eee, #fff 0 1px 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #eee, #fff 0 1px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;

  background-color: black;
  color: lightgray;
}

.not-required-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 0.5em;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 1em;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 3.5em;
  color: #999;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: text;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

/*      making exception for Budget */
.not-required-input:focus ~ .not-required-label,
.not-required-input:invalid ~ .not-required-label,
.not-required-input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .not-required-label {
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 5px;
  top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
<div class="container" >
  <input class="not-required-input" type="text" id="budget" placeholder=""/>
  <label class="not-required-label" for="budget">Budget:</label>  
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
```

What I have done is add `.not-required-input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .not-required-label` to your CSS and `placeholder=""` to the HTML. Of course, placeholders disappear when the user types into the `input`, so the pseudo `:not(:placeholder-shown)` will fire when user types into the input. I have only tested this in Firefox but it should work for all browsers. If needed, you can add a space into the `placeholder` for cross-browser support.

Comment: thank you but this is not exactly what I want... I want the label in the not required input to act it to act like other required inputs labels

Comment: @Let.Simoo You want the word Budget: to be small while there is text in the input, right?

Comment: if you try my code the budget word already getting small on focusing but my problem is it is back to big size after unfocusing

Comment: @Let.Simoo Yes, I have fixed that. You can see [your fixed codepen here](https://codepen.io/Rohittt/pen/OJbaGON)

Comment: Thank you for retrying but I solved the problem and I did what I want by following s.kuznetsov method in his reply to my question... once again thanks a lot